# com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.library. This library cannot be found

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

In domino administrator when I type : tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib
I see : 15 INSTALLED com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer.relational_9.0.1.v00_12_20150311-1316
But I don't see it as active.
When I try to use it in an application I get an error "com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.library. This library cannot be found"
What's wrong ?

**edit :**
The total result I get is :

Framework is launched.

id State       Bundle

15 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer.relational_9.0.1.v00_12_20150311-1316

17 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer.tooling_9.0.1.v00_12_20150311-1316

18 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer_9.0.1.v00_12_20150311-1316

19 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer.xspprops_9.0.1.v00_12_20150311-1316

121 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000

142 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000

145 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000

149 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000

156 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000

184 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the name of the plugin it looks like you have installed the Domino Designer plugins and not the server plugins on the server - notice the .designer.relational part of the name.

Make sure to install the plugins in the updateSiteOpenNTF.zip file and not from the updateSiteOpenNTF-designer.zip file.

Comment: Per, Could you have a look at my above edit. Do you still think I installed the wrong updateSite ?

Comment: Yes, based on the fact that the name of the plugin contains .designer